# Varying uses of COUNT and GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Quite similar to another question I've posted previously, but more complex (I think!).

I have a group of tables:

Table 1

```
 StudentId   Student     Course
 1234567     J. Bloggs   ABC      
 1234567     J. Bloggs   ABC       
 2345678     T. Test     ABC
```

Table 2

```
StudentId    Student       Module      Result      StartDate     EndDate
1234567      J. Bloggs     DEF         Fail        13/01/2014    13/03/2014
1234567      J. Bloggs     DEF         Pass        01/05/2014    15/07/2014
2345678      T. Test       DEF         Pass        13/01/2014    13/03/2014
```

What I want to do is have the SQL return, firstly how many attempts the student took at the module, and then return the most recent EndDate and Result, so something like this

```
Student     Course    Module      ModuleAttempts       Result       EndDate
J. Bloggs   ABC       ABC               2              Pass         15/07/2014
T. Test     ABC       ABC               1              Pass         13/03/2014
```

EDIT: Added initial table layouts

Comment: Have a look at GroupBy and Case When. Should be quite simple.

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ModuleAttempts = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Student, Module),
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Student, Module
                                   ORDER BY EndDate DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  Student,
        Course,
        Module,
        ModuleAttempts,
        Result,
        EndDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65750/1)

Comment: This brings back the error 'The column StartDate was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.'

Comment: @SB1987 Are you **sure** that you are using this exact query?, because I'm not specifying StartDate twice

Comment: 100% - will the fact I am selecting this data from multiple tables have any effect on the query outcome?

Comment: @SB1987 Well, of course it does, then you shouldn't be using `SELECT *`, but only use the columns that you need

Answer (score 0):

There you go: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc612/4)

```
SELECT Student, Course, Module, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.Student = t1.Student) as ModuleAttempts, 
CASE WHEN CAST(MAX(CAST(RESULT as INT)) AS BIT) = 1 THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'Fail' END as Result,
MAX(EndDate) as EndDate
FROM MyTable t1
GROUP By Student, Course, Module
```

Notes:

- Result is a bit-column in my example (Pass = 1, Failed = 0)
- The statement:
  **(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable t2 WHERE t2.Student = t1.Student)** should be t2.ID = t1.ID, instead of t2.Student = t1.Student.

Answer (score 0):

Lamak's answer is correct, but as the result contains only fail and pass the below query will also work.

```
    SELECT  Student,
            Course,
            Module,
           count(ModuleAttempts) as ModuleAttempts,
           max(Result) as Result,
--max(Result) will return "pass" (if pass exists) as it comes after fail in dictionary 
           max(EndDate) as EndDate
    from table
    group by Student,
            Course,
            Module
```

Comment: Max(result) won't work unless it's an Integer-Column

Comment: It's a varchar...max(varchar) will return pass only as pass comes after fail in dictionary

Comment: the count(*) is counting ALL module attempts, not just one's relating to that student

Comment: It should not. You can try replacing * with ModuleAttempts...edited  my post

Comment: ModuleAttempts does not exist as a field. Module does, but again when I have added count(Module), it simply counts all module attempts rather than one's for that student.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you sample data

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM
(
SELECT 'J. Bloggs' Student,   'ABC' Course,   '13/01/2014' StartDate,    '13/03/2014' EndDate,     'ABC' Module,       'Fail' Result
UNION ALL
SELECT 'J. Bloggs',   'ABC',       '01/05/2014',    '15/07/2014',     'ABC',        'Pass'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'T. Test',     'ABC',       '13/01/2014',    '13/03/2014',     'ABC' ,       'Pass'
)TAB
```

Now I have taken the `StartDate` and `EndDate` corresponding to `Student` as well as `Course`

```
SELECT Student,Course,Module,ModuleAttempts,Result,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),EndDateNew,103) EndDate
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT,Course ORDER BY CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(ENDDATE,10),105),101) AS DATE) DESC) RNO,
    COUNT(RESULT) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT,Course) ModuleAttempts,
    MIN(CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(StartDate,10),105),101) AS DATE)) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT,Course) SD,
    MAX(CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(ENDDATE,10),105),101) AS DATE)) OVER(PARTITION BY STUDENT,Course) EndDateNew  
    FROM #TEMP 
)TAB
WHERE RNO=1
```

- [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb8e2/1)

If you want to select according to module also, change

```
 PARTITION BY STUDENT,Course
```

to

```
PARTITION BY STUDENT,Course,Module
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: The problem I seem to be having is that the data comes from multiple tables (3 to be exact)

Comment: Do you mean the first table in your question? @SB1987

Comment: Yes - the data in that table comes from 3 other tables, all called by letters, so dbo.Table1 r, dbo.Table2 m, dbo.Table3 p

Comment: I think you have some problem in joins. Can you post the structure of that 3 tables with data in the question? @SB1987

Comment: Apologies, its 2 tables and I have added them to the question.

Comment: Is there a need to join Table1 with Table2? Because the columns in Table1 is the same as in Table2 according to the tables and data you have provided now. @SB1987

Comment: I have a doubt. Does the module comes under Course ie, does a Course have different modules? @SB1987

Comment: Why I asked is that there should be some relation with Course in first table and Module in second table. ie, a CourseId as reference for Module in second table @SB1987

Comment: The modules are assigned to the courses, which in turn are assigned to the students and are linked between the two tables via the StudentId field. There is a ModuleId field in Table 2 but this has no relation to Table 1.